# перевернуть массив

Tags: java, массивы

Почему не выводится перевернутый массив? то есть, последний элемент массива должен стать первым и т.д.

```
public class Mane
{


    public void sort(int[] massive){
        int[]arraySort = new int[10];
        for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--){
            arraySort[4 - i] = massive[i];
            for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
                massive[a] = arraySort[a];
            }

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        int[] mass = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Mane m = new Mane();
        m.sort(mass);
        for(int i: mass){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вы дебажить пробовали?

Comment: я конечно не эксперт, но чет код слишком запутан.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Зачем два массива, зачем вложенные циклы?

```
public void sort(int[] massive) {
    for (int i = 0; i < massive.length / 2; i++) {
        int tmp = massive[i];
        massive[i] = massive[massive.length - i - 1];
        massive[massive.length - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю почему но у меня java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой где же вы там нашли деление на 0?

Comment: не я, а студия нашла

Comment: Спросите её тогда.

Answer (score 8):

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(source)).toArray(new int[source.length]);
```

да, это будет использовать избыточные ресурсы; нет, это не страшно

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22828623/2908793

Comment: Обоснуйте фразу "нет, это не страшно". Вы случайно не разработчик Google Chrome?

Comment: Прикольно, но на примитивах не сработает, `java.util.Collections.reverse` ничего не возвращает, `toArray(new int[whatever])` тоже работать не будет. ЗИС ИЗ ЖАВА!11

Comment: Кроме того, `Arrays.asList` создает представление над массивом, и вызовы `set` на этом списке меняют исходный массив, т.е. для `Integer[] source = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` вызов `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(source))` сделает перестановку в `source`.

Comment: @zRrr да, я попался на [эту](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015999/2908793) удочку, ответ писал параллельно болтая в офисе, позор мне.

Comment: А где тут избыточные ресурсы, если не секрет?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov новый массив, плюс на тот момент думал, что внутри используется обычный ArrayList.

Comment: @Etki я думаю с текущими мощностями использовать доп структуры это не очень страшно, важнее, чтобы код был читаемым. 1 строчка эта лучше читаема, чем те 2 непонятных цикла

Comment: @AndrewBystrov поэтому после этого и идет фраза о том, что это не страшно )

Comment: Мало того, что этот код перевернет исходный массив, он еще создает как минимум две ненужные аллокации в куче и дополнительную работу для GC. И люди еще это плюсуют. А потом удивляются, почему Java так тормозит и жрет ресурсы.

Comment: @Raider вы потратите больше времени на написание цикла, чем ГЦ на выкидывание лишнего из YG за все время работы приложения.

Comment: Конечному пользователю все равно, сколько времени потрачено на код - ему главное, чтобы работало, и работало быстро. Ваш код: 1) не работает, 2) даже исправленный, создает ненужную копию массива в памяти. Если учить новичка, то зачем сразу плохому?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] =(-1)*array[i]; 
Arrays.sort(array);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] =(-1)*array[i];
```

Answer (score -1):

Всем спасибо за помощь, я разобрался

```
public class Mane
{


    public void sort(int[] massive){
        int[]arraySort = new int[5];
        for(int i = 4; i >= 0; i--){
            arraySort[4 - i] = massive[i];



        }
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            massive[a] = arraySort[a];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        int[] mass = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Mane m = new Mane();
        m.sort(mass);
        for(int i: mass){
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: А вы ответы смотрели вообще? Просто интересно.

Comment: смотрел, если интересно

Comment: Чем не устроили?

Comment: всем понравились, только почему-то не работали как надо

Comment: Используйте мой вариант с одним циклом. Он не создает копию массива, и не зависит от его длины.

Comment: спасибо, договорились